# Set display scaling when using Remote Desktop from Surface Pro

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-surface

I use my Surface Pro to remote desktop to various other machines.  When I do, the display is crazy small because Surface Pro uses 150% scaling for it's local Windows display, but this is not the default for the machines I'm remoting into.  But I can't set the scaling when I'm remoted to the other machine, because this setting can't be changed from a remote session.

Is there any convenient way to configure remote Windows machines to use the 150% display scaling when remoted into from the Surface Pro?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Nope sorry.  I never did.

Comment: Khaled's solution worked for me.  You just set up your connection, connect, then right click on it and click "Full Screen".  No additional setup was needed.  I'm quite relieved as I was about ready to take my laptop back since one of the two main purposes I bought it for (Connecting to my computer in the office and photo editing) was just not working out

Comment: @StormeHawke Khaled's steps did not work for me, going from surface 4/win10 rdp to a win 7 system. Waah!

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue, and you'll love this solution!
Download and install Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2 on your surface pro or surface pro 2, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989  -- RDP from this application and see how it works! Magic!

You can even view in Full screen, I have noticed that you need to install an update on all remote machines to be able to change the DPI using MSTSC.exe, but with Remote desktop connection manager 2.2, things just work without any update!

Comment: Yep, Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2 did the trick for me. Wrote up a blog post with screenshots: http://www.codeulike.com/2014/05/remote-desktop-on-high-dpi-screens.html

Comment: @codeulike Going from Surface 4/Win10 to Win7-SP1, the steps above and in blog do NOT result in the fix.... ack!

Comment: Your link no longer works

Comment: Apparently since they've updated Remote Desktop Connection Manager past version 2.2, this doesn't work anymore. If you have version 2.2, though, it should still work.

Answer (score 2):

The DPI synchronization is available between RDP 8.1 clients and servers only. This is described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2013/12/16/resolution-and-scaling-level-updates-in-rdp-8-1.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: DPI sync is nice and all, but all that was *really* necessary was to allow zooming in: a client-side feature that would have worked with ALL servers. Better make it a bit ugly than completely useless with Server 2008 R2...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to connect RDP session with selected session resolution and scaling using display settings for session in this app: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-remote-desktop-preview/9nblggh30h88